# Bitshifting Int16's only works with literals

Tags: c#, bit-shift, short

When I write this code in VS, it doesn't work ("Cannot implicitly convert 'int' to 'short'. An explicit conversion exists. Are you missing a cast?"):

```
short A = 5;
short B = 1 << A;
```

Yet this code is absolutely fine:

```
short A = 1 << 5;
```

I know I can make the error go away by casting the entire expression as a short, but can anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: Sounds like the bit-shift operator expects a short, not an int...C# is strongly typed.

Comment: @TheZ Er, looks like `A` was declared as a short. Hence the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because A is not a literal, the compiler doesn't know that the *result* is representable as a `short`. Therefore it needs an explicit cast. With the literal 5, the compiler sees that the result is 32, which can fit in a `short`.

Comment: Seems to me like, since A is assigned 5 at compile time, it could deduce the same conclusion as the literal 5.  But I guess the compiler assumes that there could be code that changes the value of A in between the assignment and the bit shift, and it's not smart enough to try and figure out if A was re-assigned in-between.

Comment: Right, same as in Java. But for a constant expression like `1 << 5`, the compiler can see there is no data loss.

Answer (score 2):

The C# Language specification 4.0 states in 6.1.9:

> A constant-expression (§7.18) of type int can be converted to type
>   sbyte, byte, short, ushort, uint, or ulong, provided the value of the
>   constant-expression is within the range of the destination type.

Conversion of constant expressions is one of the special cases where this will be implicit (6.1).